# Using META CHARACTERS in Conditional Statements in JS not working

Tags: javascript

I am having a terrible time with this little code..

I am trying to use Regular Expression - Meta Characters to find "Le Guin" in the "wannabe" Array without having to type "Le Guin" directly in the Conditional statement, but through using some Meta-Characters....

Funny enough I tried this yesterday and it worked but I don't know what's wrong with it now...

The "!/[Le *Guin]/" in the for Conditional statement is what am talking about...

Please what could be wrong with the code

```js
wannabe = ["Le Guin", "Ibrahim", "Ope", "You", "Le Guin", "Now", "Then", "Who", "Le Guin"];

for (a = 0; a < wannabe.length; ++a) {
    if (wannabe[a] == !/[Le*Guin]/) {
        document.write(a + ": " + "This is found at: " + a + "<br>")

        break
    } else {
        document.write(a + ": " + "not yet" + "<br>")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) or [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to check if a string matches against a regex.

Try this:

```js
let wannabe = ["Ibrahim", "Le Guin", "Ope", "You", "Le Guin", "Now", "Then", "Who", "Le Guin"];

for (let a = 0; a < wannabe.length; ++a) {
    
    if (wannabe[a].match(/Le *Guin/)) {
        
        console.log('Found');

        break;
    } 
    
    else console.log('Not yet');
}
```

Also you wouldn't need the square brackets in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
wannabe = ["Le Guin", "Ibrahim", "Ope", "You", "Le Guin", "Now", "Then", "Who", "Le Guin"];

for (a = 0; a < wannabe.length; ++a) {
    if ('Le Guin'.match(/[Le*Guin]/)) {
        console.log(a + ": " + "This is found at: " + a + "<br>")
        break
    } else {
        console.log(a + ": " + "not yet" + "<br>")
    }
}
```

There is actually match() method in js for finding string in array for regular expression.

so
use this

**if ('Le Guin'.match(/[Le*Guin]/))**